# Архитектура Android приложения

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть приложение, которое скачивает строки из сети, заносит их в БД и выводит в список на `ЭКРАНЕ 1`. Пользователь выбирает несколько вариантов из списка, и они появляются новым списком на `ЭКРАНЕ 2`. При перезагрузке приложения список не должен пропадать на `ЭКРАНЕ 2`, кроме того, пользователь может время от времени удалять/добавлять/изменять список на `ЭКРАНЕ 2`. Собственно вопрос: как реализовать данную задачу *правильно* с точки зрения ооп и андроид архитектуры?
Хранить список с `ЭКРАНА 2` в `onSaveInstance`, или создать вторую БД, и с помощью неё управлять списком на `ЭКРАНЕ 2` (не будет ли приложения тормозить из-за 2 БД?)? Или есть какой-то 3-ий правильный путь?

Comment: 1. При перезагрузк**е** приложения. 2. вторую БД создавать не нужно, достаточно создать вторую таблицу. Этот вариант правильный

Comment: @metalurgus т.е. в таких ситуация самый верный путь создавать вторую в таблица  в одной и той же БД, правильно?

Comment: Данные, сохраненные в onSaveInstance будут утрачены при выходе из приложения, вам нужна еще одна таблица с отобранными результатами в той же БД.

Comment: Причем во втоую таблицу достаточно сохранять только ID записей, отобранных из первой таблицы, то есть, между ними будет связь "один к одному"

Comment: Еще можно обойтись одной таблицей. В основной таблице сделать еще одно поле-признак, отобрана данная запись для экрана2 или нет. Затем просто делать выборку по этому полю для экрана2, в ряде сллучаев такое решение предпочтительнее